# Component state is not updated correctly while using Ionic Search Bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic with react and implemented a search functionality.

```js
const AddIngredient: React.FC<any> = ({isOpen, onClose}) => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
    const [result, setResult] = useState<Ingredient[]>([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(searchText);
        if(searchText.length > 2){
            getIngredientList(searchText)
        }
    },[searchText]);

    const getIngredientList = async(keyword: string) => {
        const result: any = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(searchIngredients, {
            filter: {name: {match: keyword}},
            limit: 50
        }));
        setResult(result.data.searchIngredients.items);
    }


    return (
        <IonModal isOpen={isOpen} cssClass='flexible-modal'>
            <IonHeader>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonTitle>ADD INGREDIENTS</IonTitle>
                </IonToolbar>
                <IonToolbar>
                    <IonSearchbar placeholder="Search Ingredients" value={searchText}
                                  onIonChange={e => setSearchText(e.detail.value!)} animated/>
                </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
        </IonModal>
    );
};

export default AddIngredient;
```

So here when ever IonChange event triggered, I am updating the state using hook and as well calling some function which fetches the result by using `useEffect`.

Here sometimes while typing in searchbar, some characters are being removed automatically even though I am updating the state for every `onIonChange` event.

```
While going through the docs I have found that 
there is a default debounce time of 250ms.
```

Does it impacting the updation of state?

But if I remove the `useEffect` hook, the state is updating in correct way..!